# Q: OrientDB - Best practices for multi tenant apps

Tags: orientdb

I'm very new to OrientDB and graphdbs in general and have some questions regarding apps that are multi-tenant.

Let's say my use case is a SaaS app where customers can create a permission model that matches their use cases. For ex:

CompanyA:
 - they model Users and Groups and Documents (with relationships between then)

CompanyB:
 - they model Users, Devices, Buildings, Badges

My SaaS app needs to be dynamic to allow customers to model whatever their needs are. I'm trying to figure out the best way to represent this in Orient. The docs mention a hard max limit on the number of `clusters` of 32,767, which means creating these entities (Groups, Devices, Documents, etc...) as Classes is a no go.

Would the correct approach be to create a generic Thing vertex class and store the entity types as attributes? Or is there a smarter way to model this in a way that can scale.

Comment: Hi did you take a look at it https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Multi-Tenant.html ?

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that... it helps clarify a few things.